# Force update to make functional component re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm doing pokedex (pokemon wiki stuff). I want to change my component view, when clicking on pokemon images (description lookalike). When I click on an image - nothing happens (firstly, I want at least pokemon's name to be added to the **pokemonDescription** array). What am I doing wrong?

```
    let pokemonDescription = [];

    const useForceUpdate = () => {
        const [value, setValue] = useState(true);
        return () => setValue(value => !value);
    }
    const forceUpdate = useForceUpdate();

    const onPokemonClick = (event) => {
        console.log(
            "wrapper clicked, event.target - ",
            event.target.getAttribute('data-name')
        );
        pokemonDescription = [];
        pokemonDescription.push(event.target.getAttribute('data-name'));
        console.log("description array -", pokemonDescription);

        forceUpdate();
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        document.querySelector(".wrapper").addEventListener("click", onPokemonClick);

        ...

        return () => {
            document.querySelector(".wrapper").removeEventListener("click", onPokemonClick);
        };
    }, []);

    ...

    return (
        <div className="Pokemons">
            <div className="column pokemons-list">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    {
                        pokemonsData.map((p, id) => (
                            <div className="box" key={ id }>
                                <img
                                    src={ p.sprites.front_default }
                                    alt="pokemon-img"
                                    title={ p.name }
                                    className="icon"
                                    data-name={p.name}
                                />
                                { p.name}
                                <div className="container">
                                    { pokemonsTypes[id] }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>

                ...

            </div>
            <div className="column description">
                { pokemonDescription }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: What is `pokemonsData`? Why isn't `pokemonDescription` in component state so the component rerenders when you update it? Why are you attaching event listeners directly to the DOM instead of the "wrapper" div in react? My guess is that even though are "forcing" a rerender, the data react is rendering isn't actually changing so you don't see any visual changes to outputted UI.

Comment: pokemonsData consists of fetched pokemon data from API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pokemonDescription` to state instead of some local variable and it will solve your issue.

Try to avoid using `forceUpdate`, most of the times it means only that you are doing something silly.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `pokemonDescription` to your component state

```
const [pokemonDescription, setPokemonDescription] = useState([]);
```

Remove the `forceUpdate` function and hook, it is unnecessary.

Attach the click handlers to the elements with the `data-name` attribute you are trying to handle.

Map the `pokemonDescription` state array to renderable JSX. I simply used a `div`, but you should use whatever your UI design requires.

```
const onPokemonClick = (event) => {
  setPokemonDescription(names => [
    ...names,
    event.target.getAttribute('data-name'),
  ]);
};

...

return (
    <div className="Pokemons">
        <div className="column pokemons-list">
            <div className="wrapper">
                {
                    pokemonsData.map((p, id) => (
                        <div className="box" key={ id }>
                            <img
                                src={ p.sprites.front_default }
                                alt="pokemon-img"
                                title={ p.name }
                                className="icon"
                                data-name={p.name}
                                onClick={onPokemonClick} // <-- attach click handler to img element
                            />
                            { p.name}
                            <div className="container">
                                { pokemonsTypes[id] }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))
                }
            </div>

            ...

        </div>
        <div className="column description">
            {pokemonDescription.map(name => (
              <div>{name}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't what that `useForceUpdate`  does , but here is how  would go about adding pokemon names to description array which is a state variable in my answer

```
    const [pokemonDescription , setPokemonDescription ] = useState(null);

    const onPokemonClick = (p) => {
        const tempPokemonDescription = [...pokemonDescription ];
        pokemonDescription.push(p.name);
        console.log("description array -", pokemonDescription);
        setPokemonDescription(tempPokemonDescription )
    };

    ...

    return (
        <div className="Pokemons">
            <div className="column pokemons-list">
                <div  className="wrapper">
                    {
                        pokemonsData.map((p, id) => (
                            <div className="box" onClick={e=>onPokemonClick(p)} key={ id }>
                                <img
                                    src={ p.sprites.front_default }
                                    alt="pokemon-img"
                                    title={ p.name }
                                    className="icon"
                                />
                                { p.name}
                                <div className="container">
                                    { pokemonsTypes[id] }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        ))
                    }
                </div>

                ...

            </div>
            <div className="column description">
                { pokemonDescription }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```